# ESLint/TSLint - add severity where array is being used in settings?

Tags: javascript, eslint, tslint

I have the following TSLint (same as ESLint) rule:

```
"rules": {
        "prefer-const": false,
        "no-trailing-whitespace": false,
        "one-line": [
            true,
            "check-catch",
            "check-finally",
            "check-open-brace",
            "check-whitespace"
        ],
```

I'm trying to set the severity of the `one-line` rule to warning, but the array of checks  does not seem to accept `"severity": "warn"`

What's the syntax to achieve this? I have found examples of using severity:warn, but not with an array of checks

**UPDATE** 
I'm finding the constant `error` warnings so distracting - especially as they appear immediately as you type - `let somVar =` gives `error: prefer-const` until I actually finish typing and do a reassign:-)
VSCode - `"tslint.alwaysShowRuleFailuresAsWarnings": true`, will do for now!! The green squiggle is barely noticable, and `Auto Fixing` also kicks in on save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify the `severity`, you can configure the `one-line` rule like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "one-line": {
            "options": [
                "check-catch",
                "check-finally",
                "check-open-brace",
                "check-whitespace"
            ],
            "severity": "warning"
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, consult the [`tslint.json` documentation](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/tslint-json/).